# Why don't these OnClick and OnKeyDown Events work?

Tags: javascript

```js
var clicks;
var time1;
var keys_pressed;
var keys_typed;

function startTrack() {
  time1 = Date.now();
  clicks = 0;
  keys_pressed = 0;
  keys_typed = 0;
}

document.onclick = function() {
  clicks++;
};
document.onkeydown = function() {
  keys_pressed++;
};

function analytics() {
  var time2 = Date.now();
  var time = time2 - time1;
  var min = Math.floor(time / 60000);
  var sec = (time % 60000) / 1000;

  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<div hidden><p>Number of mouse clicks: '+ clicks + '</p><p>Total time spent: ' + min + ' mins, ' + sec + ' secs' + '</p><p>Total key presses: ' + keys_pressed + '</p><p>Total number of characters: ' + keys_typed + '</p></div>' );

}
```

```html
<body onload="startTrack()">
...
</body>
```

I'm a complete JS beginner trying to get 2 simple events to work without using Ajax or JQuery or anything like that. All my other scripts seem to work, except the two events above where I'm just trying to store the number of keys pressed and mouse clicks **anywhere on the page**. However, the counters for both these metrics remain at zero no matter what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`/`onkeydown`.

Comment: Also, `document` represents the conceptual "document" - not the visible/rendered document and not **not** any part of it (such as the root rendered element) - you'll want `document.documentElement` to get the root `<html>`  element, or `document.body` for `<body>`.

Comment: reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for perhaps a better option

Comment: Your code does nothing that would report on what the values of those variables are. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @Dai I think that's exactly my problem. I tried it like this however and it still didn't work... `document.documentElement.addEventListener("keydown", myFunction1);
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", myFunction2);`

Comment: @chiken It works for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/0o9Lhcgw/

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `clicks++;` when it is not initialized produces `NaN` since you cannot `++` on `undefined`.

```js
var clicks;
var time1;
var keys_pressed;
var keys_typed;

function startTrack() {
  time1 = Date.now();
  clicks = 0;
  keys_pressed = 0;
  keys_typed = 0;
}

document.onclick = function() {
  clicks++;
  // without the initialization this logs NaN
  console.log("Clicks:",clicks);
};
document.onkeydown = function() {
  keys_pressed++;
  console.log("Pressed:", keys_pressed);
};
console.log(clicks);// logs "undefined"
// you need to initialize your variables so call it!
//startTrack();
```

```html
<body onload="startTrack()">
...<div>Hi there I am here! But the fish ate my bait.</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I forgot to mention it but the startTrack() function is called by the HTML document and successfully so because the time tracking for example does work.

Comment: You posted no HTML so we can only assume here - always post a full example that reproduces your issue IN the question.

Comment: Indeed. I Added the relevant HTML segment to the question.

Comment: I updated to add the body tag as you have it now and commented out the initialization of the global variables via the function - seems to work here still.

Comment: I have added the last part of my script to my original question. The element is inserted normally and when it should and the time metrics are displayed correctly but even with your code the `keys_pressed` and `clicks` vars are still 0 in the end...

Answer (score 0):

Using [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)  is better as it allows you to add multiple listeners instead of replacing a listener that might have already been there:

```js
let events = 0
const foo = document.getElementById('foo')

document.addEventListener('click', oneMore)
document.addEventListener('keydown', oneMore)

function oneMore(ev) {
  foo.textContent = ++events
}
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id=foo>Click me</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
addEventListener('click', (e) => { clicks++ })
addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { keys_pressed++ })
```

Should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).